# Better way to parse serial data without EOL character

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, desktop-application, .net-4.8

I have an xBee router (in Transparent Mode) continuously sending 32-bytes of HEX data every 30-50ms to an xBee coordinator (in API-1 Mode) that wraps the incoming data with extra bytes along with an automatically generated checksum byte at the end to complete the API frame.  I have no option to configure or add any EOL character (e.g. \r\n) to the coordinator xBee for my WPF application to parse, other than knowing each packet starts with a 0x7E byte as defined by the API-1 protocol.

As expected, the serial port fires the receiving events in-deterministically, and I would occasionally get packets in different length and the wrong starting bytes. So I set my `SerialPort.ReceiveBytesThreshold = 48` and when a receive event is fired, I also check for the starting byte to be `0x7E` and the receiving string to be `143` in length.

It works so far but the GUI appears to be somewhat *laggy* - I would occasionally see up to half a second of delay followed by a lump of data lines thrown to the screen. The lagging may have to do with `TextBox.AppendText()` and `TextBox.ScrollToEnd()` so I just replaced it by simply updating the `TextBox.Text` instead, which appears to be a lot more responsive, though if I watch closely enough the data is still not being updated as consistent or as *smooth* as it should.  I am also suspicious of how robust this method would turn out - if for whatever reason the packet gets shifted by a byte or two, I could possibly lose all of the data.

Is there a better and/or smoother way to handle these data at the serial port?

```
SerialPort _serialPort;
string _data;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
    _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
    _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
    _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 48;
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Receive);

    _serialPort.Open();
}

private delegate void UpdateUiTextDelegate(byte[] data);
private void Receive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;     
    int count = sp.BytesToRead;              
    byte[] buf = new byte[count];

    sp.Read(buf, 0, count);

    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(WriteData), buf);
}

private void WriteData(byte[] temp)
{
    string str = BitConverter.ToString(temp);

    /// The packet appeared at the COORD: 48-byte 
    /// Converted to string: 96-strings + 47-hypens = 143 letters
    if(str.StartsWith("7E") && (str.Length == 143))
    {
        //tbData.Text = str;

        tbData.AppendText(str);
        tbData.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        tbData.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Tried [if you must use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)  as suggested by JonasH. It works but lags even more so than the original approach of handling through `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` - the GUI would freeze for 3-5 seconds before updating with a larger lumps of data.

```
_serialPort.Open();
            
byte[] buffer = new byte[48];
Action kickoffRead = null;
kickoffRead = delegate {
    _serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar) {
        try
        {
            int actualLength = _serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
            byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
            Receive(received);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //handleAppSerialError(exc);
        }
        kickoffRead();
    }, null);
};
kickoffRead();
```

Comment: You might want to read [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Comment: @JonasH further to your link I've also tried another implementation of it [A Reliable Serial Port in C#](https://www.vgies.com/a-reliable-serial-port-in-c/). Same result - even slower and poorer in performance than .NET's SerialPort

Comment: Should the program always display the latest data? Even if the display is delayed for some reason, wouldn't it be nice to be able to refresh it with the latest information by noticing it and performing some operation? In that case, it would be better to consider data transmission/reception/analysis processing and screen display processing separately. Alternatively, instead of using WPF, why not write part or all of the program in C++?

Comment: I do not have much experience with serial ports. Lagging UI usually means the UI thread is blocked, but I do not see any reason for that in your example, so some profiling or measurements to check how often messages are received, and how how much time it takes to process them, might be in order. I would also have expected the hardware to ensure the byte stream is reproduced correctly, at least for a noise-free channel. If that is not the case you might have a hardware issue, loose contacts, or excessive noise. But again, I'm really not an expert.

Comment: Doing processing on a background thread is often a good idea, but only relevant if the processing takes a measurable amount of time, again, profiling might be a good idea. I would not recommend changing language or framework before first understanding the actual problem, unless doing so is faster/cheaper than other investigative techniques.